# Egghead angular controller not working

Tags: angularjs, binding, controller

I am trying to follow along on the eggheads angularJS tutorials. I have the same code however mine is not working...

Here is the code I am using:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <title>AngularJS Tutorials</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../foundation/css/foundation.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div ng-app="">
        <div ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
            <h1>{{data.message + " world"}}</h1>
            <div class="{{data.message}}">
                Wrap me with a foundation component.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.4/angular.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

main.js:

```
function FirstCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.data = {message: "panel"};
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is angular version.

Your version is `1.3.4` instead of `1.2.3`.

- App with angular 1.2.3 (egghead) : [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/eWwlv4G7WoUUu4K0sQWj?p=preview)
- App with angular 1.3.4   :[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Yv9jtPBX3GpTiUqC78vS?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

Hi you've missed couple thing

1. Declaration of you app :

   `var app = angular.module('app', []);`
2. Declaration of your controller

   `app.controller('FirstCtrl', FirstCtrl);`
3. In your html

   `ng-app="app"`

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('FirstCtrl', FirstCtrl);

function FirstCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.data = {
    message: "panel"
  };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
    <h1>{{data.message + " world"}}</h1>
    <div class="{{data.message}}">
      Wrap me with a foundation component.
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```